# restoring Webview(page) from an android activity

Tags: javascript, android

I'm loading a URL from the Main activity,

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

after performing some activities on the web, on a event, I call another activity using droidgap.
I'm not able to give back control to the webpage on finishing the activity.
Basically I need restoring/webpage mechanism where I left to the android activity.

Below are some of the snippets,
MyClass(DroidGap) giving access to JS-

```
public class MyClass extends DroidGap{
  static WebView mAppView;
  static DroidGap mGap;
  private String RInfo[] =  new String[5];

  public MyClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view)
  {
    mAppView = view;
    mGap = gap;   
  }

  public void initiateDP(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mGap, DPActivity.class);
      mGap.startActivity(intent);
  }
```

MainActivity :-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 40000);

    mc = new MyClass(this, appView);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(mc, "MyCls");

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
}
```

Index.html:-

```
alert('shaken');
           var r = window.confirm('Do you want to enable remote');
           if(r == true)
           {


                        //    alert('before redirecting');
                             window.MyCls.initiateDP();

           }
```

this starts the DPActivity. So from DPActivity, I have to come back to the page where I left. 
in DPActivity :-

```
if(MyClass.mAppView.canGoBack()) {
             MyClass.mAppView.goBack();
}
else{
finish();
}
```

this is not happening. Please suggest me any other mechanism or correct me if wrong.

Comment: If you just want the DPActivity to be gone, so you get back to your MainActivity, you should always just call `finish();` If you also want to go back a page on your MainActivity and show MainActivity again, you should also call `finish();` after the `MyClass.mAppView.goBack();`

Comment: MyClass.mAppView.canGoBack() always returns false. it just calls finish and closes the current activity. For example, If DPActivity calls one more activity,  It just closes that activity and will come back to DPActivity. I want to explicitly come back to the web page i was viewing immaterial of what activity I am in.